# Javascript mixed comparison between 2 object / array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have 2 different javascript object :

```
key = {
  id : 3, 
  name : "Leroy", 
  class : "A", 
  address : "IDN", 
  age : "17"
}
```

and ...

```
answer = {
  id : 3, 
  class : "A", 
  name : "Leroy", 
  age : "17", 
  address : "IDN"
}
```

What I wanted to do is to compare answer object with key object using (===) or (==) and will return **true**, even when the answer object key order is mixed, but as long as the value within each key is the same, it will still return **true**.

The condition will return **false** if one of the key in answer object and its value is not present, or there is a new key and value set inside the answer object.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm new here, and i found the answer from the duplicates (thanks). Should I posted it somewhere or just embed the link to it? Or not?

Answer (score 0):

```js
key = {
  id : 3, 
  name : "Leroy", 
  class : "A", 
  address : "IDN", 
  age : "17",
}

answer = {
  id : 3, 
  class : "A", 
  name : "Leroy", 
  age : "17", 
  address : "IDN"
}

   newanswer = {
  newid : 3, 
  class : "A", 
  name : "Leroy", 
  age : "17", 
  address : "IDN"
}

console.log(isequal(key,answer))
   console.log(isequal(key,newanswer ))

function isequal(prev, now) {
    var prop;
    for (prop in now) {
        if (!prev || prev[prop] !== now[prop]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const original = {id: 3, name: "Leroy", class: "A",address: "IDN", age: "17"}
const unordered = {id: 3, class: "A", name: "Leroy",age: "17",address: "IDN"}
const different = {id: 4,class: "B",name: "Lerox",age: "18",address: "IDP"}

// Is Match.
const isMatch = (A, B) => {
  const eA = Object.entries(A)
  return eA.length === Object.keys(B).length // Equivalent number of keys.
  && eA.every(([k, v]) => B[k] === v) // B contains every key + corresponding value in A.
}

// Proof.
console.log(isMatch(original, unordered)) // true
console.log(isMatch(original, different)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const keys = (o) => Object.keys(o).sort((a, b) => a > b)
const isEqual = (key, answer) => {
  let keyArr = keys(key)
  let keyLen = keyArr.length
  let answerArr = keys(answer)
  if (keyLen !== answerArr.length) return false
  for (let i = 0; i < keyLen; i++) {
    if (key[keyArr[i]] !== answer[answerArr[i]]) return false
  }
  return true
}
```